# Como mostrar somente uma item de cada no django?

Tags: html, python, django

Preciso printar no html somente os itens diferentes do meu banco de dados. Quero que mostre no link "/laranja" o seguinte:

Cores da laranja:

*verde

```
  *1,00
```

*amarelo

```
  *2,00

  *1,10
```

No código abaixo mostra o seguinte:

Cores da laranja:

*verde

```
  *1,00
```

*amarelo

```
  *2,00
```

*amarelo

```
  *1,10
```

Banco de dados:

| fruta | cor | preco |
| --- | --- | --- |
| laranja | verde | 1,00 |
| laranja | amarelo | 2,00 |
| laranja | amarelo | 1,10 |
| maça | vermelho | 1,50 |
| maça | vermelho | 2,50 |

**models.py:**

```
class Colecao(models.Model):
    fruta = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    preco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**views.py**

```
class loja(TemplateView):
      template_name = "loja.html"
      def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
           contex = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context ['cor_fruta'] = Colecao.objects.filter(fruta='laranja')
           for cores in Colecao.objects.filter(fruta='laranja'):
               context['preço_fruta'] = Colecao.objects.filter(cor=cores)
           return context
```

**fruta.html**

```
Cores da laranja
        {% for value in cor_fruta %}
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {{ value.cor }}
                    <li>{{ value.preço }}</li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        {% empty %}
        <p>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Sem registro</td>
            </tr>
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: não seria só mudar a query e incluir um group by?

Comment: vc sabe qual o comando que usa no django? tentei colocar group_by e nao deu.

Comment: consegui fazer no sqlite que é o banco de dados que estou utilizando tem que colocar ".values('campo1').distintc()"

Answer (score -2):

Depois de pesquisar por muito tempo e por tentativa e erro, consegui resolver o problema. Para mostrar os itens separados precisei mudar o views.py e o template. Era necessário agrupar o itens no SQLite é utilizado o seguinte comando .values('campo1').distintc(). Realizei as seguintes mudanças:

**views.py**

```
class loja(TemplateView):
      template_name = "loja.html"
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
               fruta = self.kwargs['fruta']
               context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
               context['cor_fruta'] = Colecao.objects.filter(fruta=fruta).values('cor').distinct()
               context['preco'] = Colecao.objects.filter(fruta=fruta).order_by("preco")
               return context
```

**fruta.html**

```
Cores da laranja
        {% for value in cor_fruta %}
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {{ value.cor }}
                    {% for nome in preco %}
                        {% if value.cor == nome.cor %}
                             <p>{{ nome.preco }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        {% empty %}
        <p>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Sem registro</td>
            </tr>
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -3):

views

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
class loja(ListView):
      model=Colecao
      template_name = "loja.html"
      context_object_name='frutas'
```

template

```
Cores da laranja
        {% for value in frutas %}
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                       {{ value.fruta }}
                        {{ value.cor }}
                    <li>{{ value.preço }}</li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        {% empty %}
        <p>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Sem registro</td>
            </tr>
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
```

tente assim

Comment: o que mandei soluciona pelo menos uma parte do seu problema k

Comment: mas se quiser saber mais sobre consulta tem o get_queryset(), acho que pode ajudar

Comment: é possível utilizar o Listview junto com o templateview? pq precisa que aparecam outras coisas no template também, por exemplo, um mapa.